# python code spontaneously stopped working

Tags: python, list, file, raspberry-pi

So I have a simple bit of code on a raspberry pi that generates a list of .txt files, encodes the list in a json object and sends it to a client:

```
def file_list(conn):
    filelist = []
    os.chdir("/home/pi/TempLog")
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        filelist.append(file)
        print file
    object = json.dumps(filelist)
    conn.sendall(object)
```

This did work at one point but now it isn't generating a file list and "print file" shows nothing.

I have made sure that there are text files in the "/home/pi/TempLog" folder and made sure the path is correct. The only code changes that I have made are to the client that I'm sending to but I commented those out and it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: You aren't calling the function

Comment: to be sure the for loop is used, add a `print 'test'` just after `for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):`

Comment: to cricket: yes i am its being called in the main i just didn't show that part. if i add a print statement like 'print "hello"' it will print 'hello'.

Comment: Try inputting the full "C:/../home/pi/TempLog" or whatever into the address bar.  And make a print statement for the cwd before the for loop just to double check you're in the right directory.  The only thing I can thing of is the for loop is looking at the incorrect directory and has no .txt files.

Comment: and also try to `print len(glob.glob("*.txt"))`

Comment: to PRMoureu: not printing in the loop. given the loop conditions this would imply that there are no files to work with but i made sure there are.

Comment: "print os.getcwd()" gives "/home/pi/TempLog" which is the correct directory. "print len(glob.glob("*.txt"))" results in a 0 but should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, try

```
import os

os.chdir("/home/pi/TempLog")
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))  # show full path to current dir
print(os.listdir())                # show what files it can see
```

Comment: those print statements are showing the correct path and directory contents.

Comment: Do the text-file names begin with a period? `*` does not match leading periods (special case, see `help(glob.glob)`).

Comment: no, no periods first one is '2017-06-27' and the second is 'tedyd'

Comment: OK never mind i found the problem. apparently you need to manually add .txt to the file name. when you make it.

Comment: Haha yep, all files created by programming languages require extensions.  Glad you found the solution.